# PHP - download a CSV file but Firefox browser detects it as Zip file

Tags: php

when i download a CSV file on Firefox browser then detect it is Zip file (must be CSV)

[image: looking at picture under]

I want to it is CSV file.

this is my the code

```
<?php
$filename = 'example.csv';
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Type: application/csv; name="' . $filename. '"');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" . rawurlencode($filename));

$th = array();
$th[] = "名前";

mb_convert_variables('SJIS','UTF-8',$th);

$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $th);
fclose($out);

ob_get_contents();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Comment: First Follow-up Question: Does it happen if you use chrome to do it ?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Please show the code you use in this.

Comment: @KenLee It does

Comment: @vee I edited the my post.

Comment: Is this the only code you have, or is there other code that could be interfering as well?

Answer (score 3):

According to [RFC7111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111), the correct MIME type for CSV file is "text/csv". Also, you don't usually need to flush the output buffer.

To give browser full information, you can try writing the CSV into buffer, calculate the buffer size for content-length, then output the buffer content.

If your file encoding is in UTF-8, this should be sufficient:

```php
<?php

// Use output buffer to prevent any warning or error from
// polluting the CSV output.
ob_start();

// CSV contents
$data = [
        ['名前', '電話番号'],
        ['David', '12345678'],
        ['John', '23456789'],
];

// write to buffer
$buffer = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($buffer, $row);
}
rewind($buffer);
$size = fstat($buffer)['size'] ?? 0;

// drop the output buffer content
// leave the $buffer content (CSV body) alone
ob_end_clean();

// Send HTTP header and content
// for the CSV response.
$filename = 'example.csv';
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; name="' . $filename. '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" . rawurlencode($filename));
echo stream_get_contents($buffer);
```

References:

1. [I/O Streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)
2. ["php://" stream wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: thank you,
but doesn't seem correct. i run again and it's still an error

Comment: What error did you see?

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't behave as you say. If you cut something out of the example you given, then the things that you cut out could be the issue. Please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: when i download on Firefox browser then it is still  Zip file

Comment: Are you using the exact code that I gave you? Nothing more and nothing less? I did tried my code on Firefox and it works normally here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bjsnY9FT-s8RHNptQuWIO9IpqavXNE_l/view?usp=sharing
i used the exact the code above which you send

Comment: Can I have the link where you hosted the code here?

Comment: @SaoMai: There are probably some server settings mingled in-between. I've updated my code to better prepare the output. Please try again.

Comment: not the above error that I said. it's a cause elsewhere in my project

Answer (score 1):

```
exit();
```

When I add the above command at the end of the file code, then it works normally again.

[image]

But I don't understand yet why adding `exit()` has this working properly

Answer (score 0):

This "error" is related to your computer file open configuration. Maybe you checked the option to assign .csv files to this zip software, but, is easy to change the software and set another one.